# Get the currency of a country with countryinfo

Tags: python

I am trying to get the currency of a country using the `countryinfo` packkage. The problem I have is that some countries return multiple 'currencies' even though only one is correct. How do I circumvent this? In other words a want a list or vector with only one currency (the correct one) for each country.

What I mean is for example: `CountryInfo('Switzerland').currencies()` or `CountryInfo('USA').currencies()` return `['CHE', 'CHF', 'CHW']` and `['USD', 'USN', 'USS']` respectively and I only want 'CHF' and 'USD'.

Comment: i dont think it can be done , its totally dependent on the package. here https://pypi.org/project/countryinfo/#currencies it returns a list

Comment: Do you know of another package that does what I need?

Comment: this might help https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/

Comment: Thank you, that's it!